# MeteorJS: working with Dynamic Subscribe/Publish

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

Here is my subscribe:

`Meteor.subscribe('jobs', Session.get('currentIndustryOnet'));`

publish:

```
  Meteor.publish('jobs', function(onet_code){
    console.log(onet_code);
    if(onet_code)
      return Jobs.find({onet: onet_code});
    else
      return Jobs.find({});
  })
```

Obviously this isn't working, but I am just not sure how to fix this. Basically, when a user selects from a drop down list of options, the subscription should update with the onet_code passed in via the Session variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing one line:

```
Deps.autorun(function (){
    Meteor.subscribe('jobs', Session.get('currentIndustryOnet'));
});
```

**Welcome to the magic of Meteor.**

To understand how this works, note that

- `Deps.autorun` calls the function again when any reactive dependencies are invalidated from the last time it was called; and
- `Deps.autorun` automatically cleans up any previous subscriptions that were started in a previous call after starting the new one.

See also http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_autorun